# Using LibTiff.Net to inject tags inside TiffTag.IMAGEDESCRIPTION damages file

Tags: libtiff.net

We are trying to inject a TimestampAnnotation into the StructuredAnnotations section of an OME-Tiff file. I'm getting the annotation in there correctly, but when I try to reload the tiff, all the images are damaged. Is there an easier way to do this?

OME is a list of classes generated from the OME-tiff schema that we obtained (then generated our own) from

https://github.com/boonepeter/OME-Tiff-Csharp

```
private bool InjectTimeStampIntoSlide()
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        using (Tiff image = Tiff.Open(SlideName, "a"))
        {
            // Image 0 must be the highest res image of the pyramid
            image.SetDirectory(0);

            // Get the Image Header for this image
            TaggedImageHeader header = new TaggedImageHeader(image);
            bool hasSubIfds = header.SubIfd > 0;
            bool hasTiles = image.IsTiled();

            if (hasSubIfds && hasTiles)
            {
                OME omeMetadata;
                var fieldValueArray = image.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEDESCRIPTION);
                string omeMetadataStr = fieldValueArray[0].ToString();
                
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OME));
                using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(omeMetadataStr))
                {
                    omeMetadata = (OME)serializer.Deserialize(tr);
                }

                // Convert to List
                List<object> lstItems = new List<object>(omeMetadata.Items.ToList());

                // Load StructuredAnnotations
                StructuredAnnotations structuredAnnotations =
                    (StructuredAnnotations)lstItems.FirstOrDefault(
                        i => i.GetType() == typeof(StructuredAnnotations));

                // We need the Index, so we can delete / replace it later
                int structuralAnnotationsIdx =
                    lstItems.FindIndex(i => i.GetType() == typeof(StructuredAnnotations));

                if (structuredAnnotations == null)
                    structuredAnnotations = new StructuredAnnotations();

                // Get and / or create list of Annotations
                List<Annotation> lstAnnotations = new List<Annotation>();
                if (structuredAnnotations.Items?.Length > 0)
                    lstAnnotations = structuredAnnotations.Items.ToList();

                // Add TimestampAnnotation
                lstAnnotations.Add(new TimestampAnnotation()
                    { Description = $"UserName: {Environment.UserName}", Value = DateTime.Now });

                // Delete old Structured Annotations
                if (structuralAnnotationsIdx >= 0)
                    lstItems.RemoveAt(structuralAnnotationsIdx);

                // Add then add new one back
                structuredAnnotations.Items = lstAnnotations.ToArray();
                lstItems.Add((object)structuredAnnotations);

                // Now update Metadata Items
                omeMetadata.Items = lstItems.ToArray();

                // And convert it to XML string
                omeMetadataStr = string.Empty;

                // Using StringWriter makes Encoding utf-16, and we need utf-8.
                // So created the class ExtendedStringWriter, and now using
                // StringBuilder to assist

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                using (ExtendedStringWriter sw = new ExtendedStringWriter(sb, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(sw, omeMetadata);
                    omeMetadataStr = sb.ToString();
                }

                image.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEDESCRIPTION, omeMetadataStr);

                success = image.WriteDirectory();
            }
        }

        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log4NetHelper.WriteExceptionToLog(Log, ex, GetType(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating an existing directory with `WriteDirectory`. This causes the data to be written in the file starting at the same location/offset. If the new size of the directory is larger than the previous one, the following data will be corrupted.

The proper way is to use `RewriteDirectory` instead of `WriteDirectory`. As stated in the documentation for this method:

> The `RewriteDirectory` operates similarly to `WriteDirectory`, but can
> be called with directories previously read or written that already
> have an established location in the file. It will rewrite the
> directory, but instead of place it at it's old location (as  would) it will place them at the end of the
> file, correcting the pointer from the preceeding directory or file
> header to point to it's new location. This is particularly important
> in cases where the size of the directory and pointed to data has
> grown, so it won’t fit in the space available at the old location.
> Note that this will result in the loss of the previously used
> directory space.

Comment: Regardless of whether I use WriteDirectory, RewriteDirectory, or CheckpointDirectory, the next time I try using NetVIPS (.NET version of libvips) to load it as an OME-TIFF file it's a damaged file.  Could it be due to the fact the tag I'm modifying is TiffTag.IMAGEDESCRIPTION???

Comment: @MichaelScott There is always a possibility for a bug in the library, but RewriteDirectory should properly update the directory no matter what tag you modify. Does any other tool except NetVIPS complain about the file being damaged? libvips?